# Create New User with info from another Model - Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails 3 and Devise for user authentication. I created a separate scaffold, request_new_user, and I want to have a link on the index page for all of the people who requested an account to go to the new_user_path, with their information sent as well to populate the fields. How would I set the params so I can set the values within the user controller? Or is there a better way to do this? I mainly just want to pass the new user's name and email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate devise views in your project by:  rails generate devise:views .

Send your params in GET request: /signup?email=...&name=...
In registration view you can apply your params, something like:

```
<%= f.input :email, :value => params[:email] %>
```

Hope it helps.